# Computer shutdown when holding keys for too long

Tags: linux, power, shutdown

I'm using a Manjaro Linux with an XMonad desktop. I'm still not able to reproduce the exact conditions of the bug but very ofter when holding a key for very long, the keyboard will freeze (just that, music and etc continues) and a few seconds later the computer will shutdown.

Is there some place where I can find power logs or keyboard logs or something that could help me? I found nothing very interesting on /var/logs.

Comment: Give information about the used hardware please. If it's a notebook, the pressure might shorten something. If it's a USB keyboard, it might be a bug of it's firmware, so it sends "shut down".

Comment: Perhaps it is some sort of accessibility thing gone wrong as well? What keys have you noticed this with and what make/model keyboard are you using? Does this happen with other keyboards? Is this a laptop? Does it happen with external keyboards? Is it related to combinations of keys (e.g. pressing too many at the same time)? Kernel crashes would generally be logged in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/kern*. Maybe something ACPI related, in /var/log/messages.log?

Comment: Just out of curiosity does it happen if you hold shift for longer than 8 seconds?

Comment: Manjaro being based on top of Arch should be using systemd, so your useful logs may appear in `journalctl -xlab -1`

Comment: It is a notebook with its usual keyboard. The error usually happens when travelling through text with arrow keys while coding, I don't know if that changes something (only if it is some kind of bad contact...). Nothing happened while holding shift.

Comment: None of the log files where present there, only some Xorg ones which weren't very interesting...

Comment: Looking at the output of journalctl I only see systemd[2025]: Stopping (..), nothing that really indicates a previous error.